# VIisual Studio Code using the wrong debugger (PLSQL Debugger) for my Python code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

very basic one here. I wrote some Python code that worked fine, then used VS Code for SQL work.

Now I want to reuse Python and try as I might I can't get it to Run without first Debugging in PLSQL Debug. Even if I choose Run -> Run Without Debugging the terminal doesn't load the results of the Python script. Instead I get in the Debug Console:

"Debug started on port 4000, waiting on the client to connect..."

I am sure there is a straightforward answer to this, but how do I get back to VS Code treating my Python code like Python code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your configurations have been changed when you first run PLSQL debug. Go to your main project path find the `.vscode` folder and delete `launch.json`.

[image: pic]

After you deleted `launch.json` file, go to `Run and Debug` and start a new python debug mode

Comment: Thanks! How do I get to this Sail menu in order to delete it? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Sail is the name of my project you can ```CTRL + Q``` to go there. (Explorer )

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can select the debug file type in **Run and Debug**.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have Python as an option for some reason. When I try Add Configuration, my options include Node.js, Chrome, Edge and so on but not Python...

Comment: @Tomalak2Pit This means that Python is not included in your `launch.json` file, and you need to add it manually. You can select `Add configuration` at the bottom. Select `Python` according to the prompt, and it will automatically create it for you.